# How to represent n-gram features in arff file?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, weka, n-gram, arff

I've been searching this issue on the net but I have not been able to find a solution.
The problem is that:
I firstly Use Weka API in java to extract n-gram features one of which I can exemplify is

```
"not good"
```

The problem starts from here:
Header of the arff file would be something like this:

```
@relation words
@attribute {0,1} not good
```

but after creating arff file, when I want to process the file, an exception is arisen which means that the structure of arff file is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the correct order for the attribute name and possible values.  Also, attribute names that contain a space must be quoted.  The example .arff file below should load.

http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html

```
@relation words

@attribute 'not good' {0,1}

@data

0
1
0
1
```